# How to get join table data and pass inside array in php

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two tables order and orderDetail. i have multiple delivery address in order detail table based on id of order table
i want to display id from order table and deliveryAddress from order detail table.i am getting below output when i print..

but unable to display delivery_address.please anyone can suggest how i display delivery_address..

```
{
  "responseData": {
    "status": 1,
    "message": "",
    "result": [
      {
        "Order": {
          "id": "677",
          "detail_location_instructions": "Near Inox"        
        },
        "OrderDetail": [
          {
            "order_id": "677",
            "delivery_address": "Smart Club Gimnasio - Avenida Álvarez Thomas, Buenos Aires, Autonomous City of Buenos Aires, Argentina"           
          },
          {           
            "order_id": "677", 
            "delivery_address": "Lower Fort Street, Dawes Point, New South Wales, Australia"          
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Order": {
          "id": "680"
        },
        "OrderDetail": []
      },
      {
        "Order": {
          "id": "684"         
        },
        "OrderDetail": [
          {           
            "order_id": "684",          
            "delivery_address": "Four Seasons - Posadas"           
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**below is my code**

```
 public function getOrderlist(){           
            if($this->processRequest){
                $err = false; 
                if(empty($this->requestData['id'])){
                    $this->responceData['message'] = "Please provide User ID";
                    $err = true;
                } 
                if(!$err){ 
                    $id = trim($this->requestData['id']);
                    $conditions = array('Order.user_id'=>$id); 
                    $data = $this->Order->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions)); 
                    if(!empty($data)){   
                        $c = array();
                        foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
                            $c[] = array(
                                'Id' => $value['Order']['id'],
                                'deliveryAddress' => $value['OrderDetail']['delivery_address']                                                  
                            );                                
                        } 
                    }
                    $this->responceData['result'] = $c;
                    $this->responceData['status'] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: the address are in array so you have to put deliveryAddress in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the deliveryAddress in array

```
$c = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
    $myOrders = [
        'Id'=>$value['Order']['id'], 
        'deliveryAddress'=>[]
    ];

    foreach($value['OrderDetail'] as $address){
        $myOrders['deliveryAddress'][] = $address['delivery_address'];
    }
    $c[] = $myOrders;                                
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

can you trying below code.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
    $c[] = array(
        'Order' => array(
            'id'=>$value['Order']['id'],
            'detail_location_instructions' => $value['Order']['detail_location_instructions'],
        ),
        'OrderDetail' => array(
            'order_id'=>$value['Order']['id'],
            'deliveryAddress' => $value['OrderDetail']['delivery_address'],
        ),
    )                              
}
```

Comment: you can provide  output result of $data = $this->Order->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions));

Answer (score 0):

There is cases where you dont get the delivery address, in that case, you need to check if it exists first. use the Hash utility for that purpose.
I transformed the data to an array, in order for the class Hash to work.

```
public function getOrderlist(){           
        if($this->processRequest){
            $err = false; 
            if(empty($this->requestData['id'])){
                $this->responceData['message'] = "Please provide User ID";
                $err = true;
            } 
            if(!$err){ 
                $id = trim($this->requestData['id']);
                $conditions = array('Order.user_id'=>$id); 
                $data =(array) $this->Order->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions)); 
                if(!empty($data)){   
                    $c = array();
                    foreach ($data as $key => $value) { 
                        $c[] = array(
                            'Id' => Hash::get($value, 'Order.id'),
                            'deliveryAddress' => current(Hash::extract($value, 'OrderDetail.{n}.delivery_address', array()))                                                 
                        );                                
                    } 
                }
                $this->responceData['result'] = $c;
                $this->responceData['status'] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```